# Different methods of calling "display dialog" - BASH/ZSH/AppleScript

Tags: bash, zsh, macos

I noticed that I use 2 different ways to call `display dialog` in my BASH and ZSH scripts.

```
osascript -e 'set dialogText to text returned of ¬
(display dialog ¬
"Insert Text" ¬
with title "Title" ¬
default answer "")'
```

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog ¬
"Insert Text" ¬
with title "Title" ¬
default answer ""' \
-e 'text returned of result'
```

Is one of the two variants generally preferred or are there advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: This is `osascript`, it has nothing to do with `bash` and `zsh`. Please change question's title.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com would likely be a better place to ask that.

Comment: Or maybe ChatGPT^^